# Get json/jsonp data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I have a problem with JSON query.

I research on the forum and a lot of other websites to find how to fix the problem, but I used probably all of the options to repair my script...

At the moment my script:

```js
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: "http://target.xyz/?f=json",
 dataType: 'JSONP',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Before the script, I use normal JSON but I saw:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://target.xyz/?f=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mypage.xyz' is therefore not allowed access.

When I use JSONP on my target website, I get data but website returned:

> one error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Response data:

```html
{
    "date" : "2017-05-29",
    "gold" : "1267.00",
    "silver" : "17.39",
    "platinum" : "956.05"
}
```

Please give me some advice or links. Thanks.

Comment: If the api isn't cors enabled or configured to serve jsonp you need to use a proxy, either on your server or third party service. Not all api's are ajax accessible

Comment: _"When I use JSONP on my target website, I get data but website returned:"_ So you get all the Data you want from the site? What Token is Unexpected?

Comment: I have only Network request in Console. JSON: `Object {date: "2017-05-29", gold: "1267.00", silver: "17.39", platinum: "956.05"}`

Comment: Looks you are using two difrent projects for UI and API. You need to enable the CORS and make sure the API returns JSON not XML.

Comment: the JSON is valid, and you get a syntax error, if it would be the response format the guilty, it would be rather be a parse error. Can it be the `callback` function? what is its code? do you have a line number for the error that can help you find where it is?

Comment: @Kaddath error is in `2: "date" : "2017-05-29",`

Comment: @RakeshBurbure CORS is required? I never enjoyed the method. Do you know others method?

Comment: @kamil220 what Rakesh Burbur is saying is that if you also have control on the site you request, you can edit its script to enable CORS. But your problem seems different, in my opinion the site answers well and the response is valid, it may be what you do with it that causes the error. JSON is not valid javascript and would produce this exact error if you try to execute as js. You must use `JSON.parse(data)` to get a js object

Comment: i think `JSONP` should not be in capital: `"jsonp"`, but i expect jQuery to be smart enough, am i wrong?

Comment: @Kaddath No difference. I don't have access to server with data and CORS is not good idea... Problem solved. I used file_get_contents, simplexml_load_string, json_encode, json_decode.